# What is the error in this bubble sort code?

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I wrote this simple code for bubble sort but it gives some random garbage values as output. Can someone please tell me my mistake. I tried to print the output of `A[i]` and `A[j]` in the function `bubbleSort` and looks like it is working fine. But why is the `printSortedArray` not giving the correct output? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
void printSortedArray(int A[],int size)
{
    cout<<"the sorted array is"<<endl;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++);
    {
        cout<<A[i]<<" ";
    }
}
void bubbleSort(int A[],int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size-1-i;j++)
        {
            if(A[j]>A[j+1])
            {
                swap(A[j],A[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[50]; int size,i;
    cout<<"enter the size of the array: ";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Enter the "<<size<<" numbers to be sorted"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
       cin>>A[i];
    }

    bubbleSort(A,size);
    printSortedArray(A,size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What data are you giving it? What is the smallest array which causes the error?

Comment: Any data. Even if I enter an array of size 2 if gives random output. For example when i enter these two values 4, 2 the output is 13110352. It Just generates some random numbers on different inputs.

Comment: You ought to have tested the output function before you started writing the sorting function.

Comment: Note that you're actually calling the standard library `std::swap` function which takes references instead of your own `swap` function taking pointers.

Comment: Oh yes. I didn't see that. Thank's Alex.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular formatted initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<size;i++);
```

The trailing semicolon does not belong there. This results in undefined behavior.

The end result is that this function printed one garbage value after the end of the array.